# Information about space station design in the Alliance-Union universe?

Tags: space-station, alliance-union

I am trying to locate information on the space stations in C.J. Cherryh's [Alliance-Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance%E2%80%93Union_universe) universe.  I know that each space station is made to the same blueprint so they are all similar in size/design.

But is there any source that gives dimensions, sustainable population and max. docked ships?

Comment: I would suggest looking at this. It wont probably answer all of your questions and it is fanmade but it does look like the guy did his homework :D
 https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~seb/celestia/pell/index.html#0.0